# How to pass variable via AJAX / jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, ajax

I would like to know how do I pass a variable to another php-file via AJAX?

The variable that has to be passed is called:

```
$id
```

The problem is that my form in 'pm_form.php' has no access to the variable '$id'.

My script looks like this (this script fires a modal-window and that modal window loads a form called 'pm_form.php'):

```
$(".pm_link").colorbox($.extend(defaults, {
        initialWidth:'348',
        initialHeight:'348',
        innerWidth:'348',
        innerHeight:'348',
        type: "POST",
        href: "<?php echo $setting['site_url'];?>/includes/forms/pm_form.php",
    
        onComplete: function(){
            $("#cboxLoadedContent").appendTo("#cboxContent");
                            
            var title = 'Send Message';
            $('#cboxTitle').text(title);
        }
    }));
```

When I click on a submit button of my form the variable '$id' shall be passed to the appropriate php-file.

This is my form:

```
<div id="pm_content" class="modal_font_indent">
<div id="pm_form">
    <form name="form1" method="post" action="<?php echo $setting['site_url']?>/index.php?id=<?php echo $id;?>&task=send_message&done=1">
    
        <div id="pm_subject" class="form_alt_design">
            <div id="pm_subject_txt"><label for="message_title">Subject:</label></div>
            <input type="text" name="message_title" id="message_title" class="pm_subject_textbox" value="" />
        </div>
    
        <div id="pm_message" class="form_alt_design">
            <div id="pm_message_txt"><label for="message">Message:</label></div>
            <textarea name="message" cols="50" rows="4" id="message" class="pm_message_textbox"></textarea>
            <div id="pm_chars_left">Characters left:</div>
        </div>    
        
        <div id="pm_submit">
            <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="" class="pm_button" />
        </div>
        
    </form>
</div>
</div>
```

I don't know much about jQuery / AJAX.

### Solution

I just echo my $id:

href: "/includes/forms/pm_form.php?id=",
and in my pm_form.php, I can grab that id parameter using the $_GET global as:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
```

Comment: Is that a variable from PHP or JavaScript. Because it is valid syntax for both languages.

Comment: When you click on a button called 'Send PM' a MODAL-window shows up. The script that fires the modal-window is '.pm_link'. That modal window loads the form called pm_form.php. The problem is that I don't have access to the variable called '$id'. Basically I just need access to that variable so I was wondering if there is a way to pass that variable from one script to another.

Comment: Why the down-votings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pass variable from one PHP page to another, you need to use POST or GET method. Use POST['name of tag'] and store it in a separate variable.

Eg. : $variable1 = $_POST[name];

Answer (score 1):

Since you are sending value as POST
You can read that value in the other page as $_POST['value_from_previous_page'];

This is what i use to send form value to another page

```
function Gonder()
{
    var str = $("form").serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "other_page.php",
        data: str,
        success: function(data){
            $('#load').fadeOut();
            $('#ShowResult').html(data);
        }
    });
return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "some.php",
  data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
}).done(function( msg ) {
  alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
});
```